# Creating a subject and grading system in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a gradingsystem for a UNI project. 
we are told to have 3 global lists:

```
Emner = ["INFO100","INFO104","INFO110","INFO150","INFO125"]
FagKoder = [["Informasjonsvitenskap","INF"],["Kognitiv vitenskap","KVT"] 
Karakterer=[["INFO100","C"],["INFO104","B"],["INFO110","E"]]
```

With these lists we are suppost to create a way to view the subjects(Emner), with grades from Karakterer, but we should also be able to view subjects without grades. It should be displayed like this:

[image: View of how to print subjects with and without grades]
We should also be able to add new subjects in (Emner) and add new Grades in (Karakterer). All of this should be displayed as in the picture above.

I have been trying all different kind of ways of doing this, but i keep returning to one of two problems. Either im not able to print a subject without a grade, or if i add a new subject(Emne), and want to add a grade(Karakter) i am not able to place it to the right Subject, as it just saves at the first one without a grade.

hope anyone can help me with this, going crazy here!

Code i have so far:

```
def emneliste():
global Emner
global Karakterer
emne,kar = zip(*Karakterer)
ans = [list(filter(None, i)) for i in itertools.zip_longest(Emner,kar)]

def LeggTilEmne():
global Karakterer
global Emner
nyttEmne = input("Skriv ny emnekode (4Bokstaver + 3 tall): ")
if nyttEmne not in Emner:
    while re.match('^[A-Å]{3,4}[0-9]{3}$',nyttEmne):
            Emner.append(nyttEmne)
            print(nyttEmne + " Er lagt til!")
            start()
            print("Feil format")
            LeggTilEmne()

else:
    print("Dette Emnet er allerede i listen din")
    start()

def SettKarakter():
global Karakterer
global Emner
VelgEmne = input("Hvilke emne? ")

Emne,Karakter = zip(*Karakterer)
if str(VelgEmne)  not in str(Emner):
    print("Dette faget er ikke i din liste")
    feil = input("om du heller ønsket å opprette fag trykk 2, ellers trykk enter ")
    if feil == str(2):
      LeggTilEmne()
    else:
      start()

else:
      if str(VelgEmne) in str(Karakterer):
        index = Karakterer.index([VelgEmne,"C"])
        Karakterer.pop(index)
        SettKar = input("Karakter? ")
        Emner.append([VelgEmne,SettKar])
        print("Karakter " + SettKar + " Er Lagt til i " + VelgEmne)
        start()
      else:
        SettKar = input("Karakter? ")
        if str(VelgEmne) in str(Emner):
          index = Emner.index(VelgEmne)
          print(index)
          Emner.pop(index)
          Emner.insert(index,[VelgEmne,SettKar])
          print("Karakter " + SettKar + " Er Lagt til i " + VelgEmne)
          start()
        else:
          print("Virker Ikke")
          start()
```

Comment: Show the code attempts that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Karakterer` a dict instead so that you can iterate through the subjects in `Emner` and efficiently look up if a subject is in `Karakterer` with the `in` operator:

```
Karakterer = dict(Karakterer)
for subject in Emner:
    print(*([subject] + ([Karakterer[subject]] if subject in Karakterer else [])))
```

This outputs:

```
INFO100 C
INFO104 B
INFO110 E
INFO150
INFO125
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated GradeHandler class demo.  I tried to allow for updating grades, removing subjects, etc.:

```
__name__ = 'DEMO'

class GradeHandler(object):

    EMNER = ["INFO100","INFO104","INFO110","INFO150","INFO125"]
    FAGKODER= [["Informasjonsvitenskap","INF"],["Kognitiv vitenskap","KVT"]]
    KARAKTERER = [["INFO100","C"],["INFO104","B"],["INFO110","E"]]

    def __init__(self):
        self.Emner = self.EMNER
        self.FagKoder = self.FAGKODER
        self.Karakterer = self.KARAKTERER
        self.__create_grade_dict()



    def remove_subject(self, subject_name):
        """
        Remove a subject ot the classes class list variable.
        """
        try:
            self.Emner = [i for i in self.EMNER if i != subject_name]
            self.__create_grade_dict()
        except ValueError:
            pass


    def add_subject(self, subject_name):
        """
        Append a subject ot the classes class list variable.
        """
        if not subject_name in Emner:
            self.Emner.append(subject_name)
            self.__create_grade_dict()



    def __create_grade_dict(self, grade_dict=None):
        """
        Split grades matrix into separate parts; Create and set a dictionary of values.
        """
        if grade_dict is None:
            self.grade_dict = dict()

        sub, grade = zip(*self.Karakterer)
        karakterer_dict = {k:v for k, v in list(zip(sub, grade))}

        for i in self.Emner:
            if i in karakterer_dict.keys():
                self.grade_dict[i] = karakterer_dict[i]
            else:
                self.grade_dict[i] = ''



    def update_grade(self, subject_name, grade='A'):
        """
        Update a grade in the grade dictionary.
        Will also add a subject if not alrady in the dictionary.
        """
        try:
            self.grade_dict[subject_name] = grade
        except (KeyError, ValueError):
            pass




    def print_grades(self, subject_name=None):
        """
        Print dictionary results.
        """
        if subject_name is None:
            for k, v in self.grade_dict.items():
                print('{} {}'.format(k, v))

        else:
            if subject_name in self.grade_dict.keys():
                print('{} {}'.format(subject_name, self.grade_dict[subject_name]))




if __name__ == 'DEMO':

    ### Create an instance of the GradeHandler and print initial grades.
    gh = GradeHandler()
    gh.print_grades()


    ### Append a class
    gh.add_subject('GE0124')
    gh.print_grades()


    ### Add grade 
    gh.update_grade('GE0124', 'B+')
    gh.print_grades()


    ### Update grades
    gh.update_grade('GE0124', 'A-')
    gh.print_grades()


    ### Remove subject (will also remove grade.
    gh.remove_subject('GE0124')
    gh.print_grades()
```